# Is it possible to write a test that can test an AuthorizationPolicy Object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, .net-core

I've got a policy that I want to test in C#

```
public class WorkflowCreatePolicy
{
    public AuthorizationPolicy AuthorizationPolicy =>
        new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireClaim("scope", "WorkflowAdmin")
            .Build();
}
```

Does anyone know of a way to test the AuthorizationPolicy to confirm that the scope "WorkflowAdmin" is successful and all others aren't?

This is what I see when I inspect the object:

[image]

I've managed to find this website: [Authorization Handler Unit Tests](http://blog.stoverud.no/posts/how-to-unit-test-asp-net-core-authorizationhandler/) but its talking about testing handlers and has code that marks the auth attempt as successful.

i'm not sure if this is getting close or not.  It currently doesn't pass

```
[Test]
public void GivenPolicyName_WhenICallPolicyChecks_ThenItPasses()
{
    ClaimsPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { new Claim(CustomClaims.Scope, "WorkflowAdmin") }));

    WorkflowCreatePolicy workflowCreatePolicy = new WorkflowCreatePolicy();

    AuthorizationHandlerContext authorizationHandlerContext = new AuthorizationHandlerContext(workflowCreatePolicy.AuthorizationPolicy.Requirements, user, null);

    Assert.That(authorizationHandlerContext.HasSucceeded, Is.EqualTo(true));
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this test](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c376e833e46497fbec4bd7b39632f8c8e13360b2/src/Security/Authorization/test/DefaultAuthorizationServiceTests.cs#L41) in the ASP.NET Core Security Unit Tests.  I've taken the pattern from it and applied it to your policy.

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task ShouldAllowIfScopeClaimWorkflowAdminIsPresent()
{
    // Arrange
    var authorizationService = BuildAuthorizationService(services =>
    {
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("SomePolicyName", new WorkflowCreatePolicy()
               .AuthorizationPolicy);
        });
    });
    var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(
        new Claim[] { new Claim("scope", "WorkflowAdmin") }));

    // Act
    var allowed = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(user, "SomePolicyName");

    // Assert
    Assert.True(allowed.Succeeded);
}
```

```cs
private IAuthorizationService BuildAuthorizationService(
    Action<IServiceCollection> setupServices = null)
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddAuthorization();
    services.AddLogging();
    services.AddOptions();
    setupServices?.Invoke(services);
    return services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IAuthorizationService>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Under the hood an `AuthorizationPolicy` is just a collection of authorization handlers. Methods like `RequireClaim` add handlers build by Microsoft to the collection. In this case the `ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement` which inherits from `AuthorizationHandler`.

To validate if a user passes an `AuthorizationPolicy` you need an `AuthorizationService` which will call all policies. The `DefaultAuthorizationService` will stop after the first handler has failed to authenticate the user. If you do not register another `AuthorizationService` this one will be used.

So you could build the `AuthorizationService` by yourself and call the `AuthorizeAsync` method on it. Just be aware that you need to register your custom `AuthorizationHandler`'s too if you want to test against them.

```
private static async Task<bool> CanAuthorizeUserWithPolicyAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, AuthorizationPolicy policy)
{
    var handlers = policy.Requirements.Select(x => x as IAuthorizationHandler).ToArray();
    // add your custom authorization handlers here to the `handlers` collection

    var authorizationOptions = Options.Create(new AuthorizationOptions());

    authorizationOptions.Value.AddPolicy(nameof(policy), policy);

    var policyProvider = new DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider(authorizationOptions);
    var handlerProvider = new DefaultAuthorizationHandlerProvider(handlers);
    var contextFactory = new DefaultAuthorizationHandlerContextFactory();

    var authorizationService = new DefaultAuthorizationService(
        policyProvider, 
        handlerProvider, 
        new NullLogger<DefaultAuthorizationService>(), 
        contextFactory, 
        new DefaultAuthorizationEvaluator(), 
        authorizationOptions);

    var result = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(user, policy);
    return result.Succeeded;
}
```

You can use this method like the following.

```
var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { new Claim("scope", "WorkflowAdmin") }));

var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireClaim("scope", "WorkflowAdmin")
    .Build();

Assert.That(await CanAuthorizeUserWithPolicyAsync(user, policy), Is.EqualTo(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it :)

```
[TestFixture]
public class WorkflowCreatePolicyTests
{
    [Test]
    public void GivenAuthorizationPolicy_WhenICheckTheClaimScopes_ThenItHasUserAdmin()
    {
        AuthorizationPolicy authorizationPolicy = new WorkflowCreatePolicy().AuthorizationPolicy;
        ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement claimsAuthorizationRequirement = authorizationPolicy.Requirements
            .FirstOrDefault(x => (x as ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement)?.ClaimType == "scope")
            as ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement;

        Assert.That(claimsAuthorizationRequirement?.AllowedValues, Contains.Item("WorkflowAdmin"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem myself and [found these very helpfull examples on GitHub](https://github.dev/kaiyuanshe/open-hackathon/blob/945c4fd2755f5b0dea11e54eb649eeb37ec93d01/src/open-hackathon-server/Kaiyuanshe.OpenHackathon.ServerTests/Auth/PlatformAdministratorHandlerTest.cs#L35#L52).

I was able to test authorization policies like this:

```
[TestFixture]
    public class PlatformAdministratorHandlerTest
    {
        [Test]
        public async Task HandleAsyncTest_IsPlatformAdmin()
        {
            // data
            var requirements = new List<IAuthorizationRequirement>
            {
                new PlatformAdministratorRequirement(),
            };
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                ClaimsHelper.PlatformAdministrator("userid"),
            };
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
            var context = new AuthorizationHandlerContext(requirements, claimsPrincipal, null);

            // test
            var handler = new PlatformAdministratorHandler();
            await handler.HandleAsync(context);

            Assert.IsTrue(context.HasSucceeded);
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task HandleAsyncTest_IsNotPlatformAdmin()
        {
            // data
            var requirements = new List<IAuthorizationRequirement>
            {
                new PlatformAdministratorRequirement(),
            };
            var claims = new List<Claim>();
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
            var context = new AuthorizationHandlerContext(requirements, claimsPrincipal, null);

            // test
            var handler = new PlatformAdministratorHandler();
            await handler.HandleAsync(context);

            Assert.IsFalse(context.HasSucceeded);
        }
    }
```

Source:

Answer (score -2):

IMHO that's something you would want to test with [integration tests](http://ilkinulas.github.io/assets/integration_tests/no_integration_test.gif).

[Unit testing it is covered by the ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Test/AuthorizationPolicyFacts.cs) and at the end of the day you want to make sure that access to your end-points are protected as you expect.

That you can do with [TestServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing).

It's the composition of the app that shall be tested at that point: Making sure that calling your end-points without the desired claim will result in a 403.

Comment: Don't you think it is important to unit test the security policies?  Why wouldn't I want unit tests of my custom handlers (and maybe requirements)?