# How to test Test AuthorizationHandler properly

Tags: .net, .net-core, nunit, asp.net-core-webapi

I searched the web and I couldn't find one that will solve my problem. I created a custom policy based authorization in .NET core

```
//Group.cs
public class Group
{
    public string GroupType { get; set; }
    public string GroupValue { get; set; }
}

//AuthorizeAdmin.cs
public class AuthorizeAdmin : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeAdmin() : base(AuthorizationPolicyNames.Admin)
    {
    }
}

//AdminClaimRequirement.cs
public class AdminClaimRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public Group Group { get; private set; }

}

public AdminClaimRequirement()
{
    Group group = new Group();
    claim.GroupType = "groups";
    claim.GroupValue = "SiteAdmin";

    Group = group;
}

//AdminClaimRequirementHandler.cs
public class AdminClaimRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AdminClaimRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AdminClaimRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.HasClaim(requirement.Group.GroupType, requirement.Group.GroupValue))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

//AuthorizationPolicyNames.cs
public static class AuthorizationPolicyNames
{
    public static string Admin => "AdminOnly";
}
```

And this how I used in my controller

```
[ApiController]
[AuthorizeAdmin]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{

}
```

I followed this [Unit test AuthorizationHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272610/unit-test-authorizationhandler)

this http://blog.stoverud.no/posts/how-to-unit-test-asp-net-core-authorizationhandler/

and this [Is it possible to write a test that can test an AuthorizationPolicy Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651152/is-it-possible-to-write-a-test-that-can-test-an-authorizationpolicy-object)

but couldnt make it work...

This is my solution for now but I dont know how to use my policies I created

```
[Test]
    public async Task AdminAuthorizationHandler_Should_Succeed()
    {
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<System.Security.Claims.Claim> { new System.Security.Claims.Claim("groups", "SiteAdmin") }));

        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
             .RequireClaim("groups", "SiteAdmin")
             .Build();

        Assert.That(await CanAuthorizeUserWithPolicyAsync(user, policy), Is.EqualTo(true));
    }

private static async Task<bool> CanAuthorizeUserWithPolicyAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, AuthorizationPolicy policy)
    {
        var handlers = policy.Requirements.Select(x => x as IAuthorizationHandler).ToArray();
        // add your custom authorization handlers here to the `handlers` collection

        var authorizationOptions = Options.Create(new AuthorizationOptions());

        authorizationOptions.Value.AddPolicy(nameof(policy), policy);

        var policyProvider = new DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider(authorizationOptions);
        var handlerProvider = new DefaultAuthorizationHandlerProvider(handlers);
        var contextFactory = new DefaultAuthorizationHandlerContextFactory();

        var authorizationService = new DefaultAuthorizationService(
            policyProvider,
            handlerProvider,
            new NullLogger<DefaultAuthorizationService>(),
            contextFactory,
            new DefaultAuthorizationEvaluator(),
            authorizationOptions);

        var result = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(user, policy);
        return result.Succeeded;
    }
```

also this

```
[Test]
    public async Task AdminAuthorizationHandler3_Should_Succeed()
    {

        // Arrange
        var authorizationService = BuildAuthorizationService(services =>
        {
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationPolicyNames.Admin, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AdminClaimRequirement()));

            });
        });
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new System.Security.Claims.Claim[] { new System.Security.Claims.Claim("groups", "SiteAdmin") }));

        // Act
        var allowed = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(user, AuthorizationPolicyNames.Admin);

        // Assert
        Assert.True(allowed.Succeeded);
}
```

My goal is to test the AdminClaimRequirement / AdminClaimRequirementHandler not the controller.

Answer (score 1):

U can test the handler using the following (Xunit) in .Net Core 2.2

```
        [Fact]
    public async Task AdminAuthorizationHander_ShouldSucceed()
    {
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<System.Security.Claims.Claim> { new System.Security.Claims.Claim("groups", "SiteAdmin") }));

        var requirement = new AdminClaimRequirement();

        var context = new AuthorizationHandlerContext(new List<IAuthorizationRequirement> { requirement }, user, null);

        var handler = new AdminClaimRequirementHandler();

        await handler.HandleAsync(context);

        Assert.True(context.HasSucceeded);
    }
```

Comment: I'd just like to say that this is a great a very clear / minimalistic  example.